# How can I download ChromeDriver to NitrousIO Box Path?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nitrousio

I'm trying to use the watir-webdriver to build a webscraper but I'm getting an error message about being unable to find the firefox binary. Well, I'm not using firefox, I'm using Chrome.

So now I need to install the ChromeDriver binary and put in my PATH. Problem is, I have know idea how to do that in the NitrousIO IDE.

UPDATE: I downloaded and unzipped the 64bit binary. Now I'm trying to put it in my path. Eventually I got echo $PATH to read the binary, but I'm still getting an 'unable to find webdriver executable' error.

I tried mving the file into usr/bin but I got a permission denied error. Does anyone know a solution to this?